# Access color string from code behind in .css-File in ASP

Tags: css, asp.net, code-behind

I have 3 files for my Login-Screen: `Login.aspx`, `Login.aspx.cs`, `LoginStyle.css`

On the `Page_Load` method I am recieving some data from the current system among other things the **theme-color** as string (e.g *#003b67*).

In my .css-File i have defind 3 style rules, which should use this color.

```
.linkButtonPassword:hover {
        color: #38d39f;
}

.login-input-div.focus > .login-faItem > i {
    color: #38d39f;
}

.login-input-div:before, .login-input-div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #38d39f;
    transition: .4s;
}
```

so my question is, is there a way to replace the current color-string "#38d39f" with my color from code behind without defining the style in my .aspx-File? (is there a way to access a kind of variable in my css-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS files aren't processed by ASP.NET (unless you reconfigure your entire HTTP pipeline, which is a bad idea in general), so the short answer is "no".

...however a solution exists with CSS Custom Properties!

### Part 1:

In your `.aspx` page, ideally in the `<head>` (you're using `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder`, I hope?), put this **after** your current `<link rel="stlyesheet">` element:

```
<style type="text/css">
:root {
    --theme-color: <%= this.customColor %>;
}

.linkButtonPassword:hover,
.login-input-div.focus > .login-faItem > i,
.login-input-div:before,
.login-input-div:after {
    color: var(--theme-color);
}
</style>
```

You could argue this is the same thing as overwriting the properties with `<%= %>` directly - but the difference here is that you can now remove the `color:`  property from the above and use `color: var(--theme-color);` directly in your `.css` file!

### Part 2:

So now your `<head>` should contain this:

```
<style type="text/css">
:root {
    --theme-color: <%= this.customColor %>;
}
</style>
```

And your `.css` file should contain this:

```
.linkButtonPassword:hover {
    color: #38d39f;
    color: var(--theme-color);
}

.login-input-div.focus > .login-faItem > i {
    color: #38d39f;
    color: var(--theme-color);
}

.login-input-div:before,
.login-input-div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #38d39f;
    background-color: var(--theme-color);
    transition: .4s;
}
```

The `color` values are repeated twice (first as a literal hex-color, then again with `var(--theme-color)`) to ensure backwards compatibility with older browsers that don't support CSS Custom Properties (i.e. IE11 - which I assume you have to support seeming as you're using ASP.NET WebForms).

Comment: thanks! especially `<%= this.customColor %>;` helped me the access the color. Still defining styles in my .aspx file, but this works for me :)